# Random Coin Flipper output number of times run

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am attempting to write a program in  java that flips an imaginary coin and outputs the flips and then when a certain side has been flipped 3 times, it stops and tells you the number of times it flipped. My program doesn't seem to be working

My code is below:

```
 import java.util.*;
public class FlipperThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        boolean fin = false;
        while(!fin){
            System.out.println("Welcome to Flipper!");
            int h = 0;
            int hcount = 0;
            int tcount = 0;
            int ocount = 0;
            String random;
            String[] ht;
            boolean done = false;
            while(!done){
                for(hcount<3||tcount<3){ht = new String[] {"Heads","Tails"};
                Random r =new Random();
                random = ht[r.nextInt(ht.length)];
                System.out.println(random);
                }
                if (hcount!=3||tcount!=3){
                    if(random == ht[h]){
                        hcount++;
                        ocount++;
                        tcount = 0;
                    }else{
                        hcount = 0;
                        tcount++;
                        ocount++;
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("BINGO!That only took " + ocount+" flips to get 3 in a row!");
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }fin = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to be resetting tcount=0 and hcount=0 , your program probably will run forever.

Comment: it is doing that so that I dont have it stop the program on 3 occurences that arent consecutive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In general your program is much more complicated than necessary. You only need a single loop
2. You were using `==` to compare strings. Instead of `random == ht[h]` you should say `random.equals(ht[h])`
3. Instead of looping while *either* heads or tail counts are less than 3, you only want to keep looping while *both* are less than three. So instead of `hcount!=3 || tcount!=3` it's `hcount!=3 && tcount!=3`

.

```
 public class FlipperThree {

     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         System.out.println("Welcome to Flipper!");
         int h = 0;
         int hcount = 0;
         int tcount = 0;
         int ocount = 0;
         String[] ht = new String[] {"Heads","Tails"};
         Random r =new Random();

         while (hcount < 3 && tcount < 3) {
             String random = ht[r.nextInt(ht.length)];
             System.out.println(random);
             if(random.equals(ht[h])){
                 hcount++;
                 ocount++;
                 tcount = 0;
             }
             else{
                 hcount = 0;
                 tcount++;
                 ocount++;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("BINGO!That only took " + ocount+" flips to get 3 in a row!");
     }
 }

$ java FlipperThree
Welcome to Flipper!
Tails
Heads
Heads
Tails
Heads
Heads
Tails
Tails
Tails
BINGO!That only took 9 flips to get 3 in a row!
```

Comment: I want it so that only one of either needs to have been flipped 3 times

Comment: Exactly, and that's how it is here.  By saying `while (hcount < 3 && tcount < 3)` you exit the loop as soon as _either_ count reaches 3!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` and init `ht` once and remove your first `while` too and change `||` to `&&`:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FlipperThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

            System.out.println("Welcome to Flipper!");
            int h = 0;
            int hcount = 0;
            int tcount = 0;
            int ocount = 0;
            String random;
            String[] ht = new String[] {"Heads","Tails"};
            boolean done = false;

            while(!done){
                Random r =new Random();
                random = ht[r.nextInt(ht.length)];
                System.out.println(random);

                if (hcount!=3 && tcount!=3){
                    ocount++;

                    if(random == ht[h]){
                        hcount++;
                        tcount = 0;
                    }else{
                        hcount = 0;
                        tcount++;
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("BINGO!That only took " + ocount+" flips to get 3 in a row!");
                    done = true;
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: That makes the program loop for ever and also, it has this as a sample output Welcome to Flipper!
Heads
Tails
Heads
Tails
Heads
Heads
Heads
Tails
BINGO!That only took 7 flips to get 3 in a row!

Comment: Now, it doesn't show the final line and it countinues past the 3 in row

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with much simpler code when you realize that you just need to keep track of the number of consecutive coin faces. It doesn't matter what face it is:

```
/**
 * return:
 *    the number of coin tosses until you get the same face n consecutive times
 */
static int numTossesUntilNConsecutiveFaces(int n) {
    Random toss = new Random();
    // This counts the number of consecutive faces following a given face
    // For example:
    // for sequence 1 0, numConsecutive == 0
    // for sequence 1 1, numConsecutive == 1
    // for sequence 0 0 0, numConsecutive == 2
    int numConsecutives = 0;
    int numTosses = 0;
    // Initialize the lastCoin value as -1, so the first coin won't be equal to it
    int lastCoin = -1;
    do {
        // The result of the toss will be 0 or 1 (head or tails)
        int coin = toss.nextInt(2);
        if (coin == lastCoin) {
            // If the current coin is the same as the last coin, increment the counter
            numConsecutives++;
        } else {
            // If it is different, reset the counter
            numConsecutives = 0;
        }
        // Make this coin the last coin
        lastCoin = coin;
        numTosses++;
    // Stop when the number of consecutives is n - 1.
    // For n == 3, that is when the last three numbers were 1 1 1 or 0 0 0
    } while (numConsecutives < n - 1); 
    return numTosses;
}
```

Then you just need to call:

```
int tosses = numTossesUntilNConsecutiveFaces(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FlipperThree {
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         System.out.println("Welcome to Flipper!");
         int previousFlip = -1;
         int continuousFlip = 0;
         int totalFlips = 0;
         String[] ht = new String[] {"Heads","Tails"};
         Random r = new Random();
         while (continuousFlip < 3) {
             int r = r.nextInt(ht.length);
             totalFlips++;
             System.out.println(ht[r]);
             if(previousFlip == r){
                 continuousFlip++
             } else {
                 continuousFlip = 1;
                 previousFlip = r;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("BINGO!That only took " + totalFlips +" flips to get 3 in a row!");
     }
 }
```

Just wanted to show a shorter version. Whole point is that you don't need to keep track of BOTH the heads or tails, you just need to keep track of how much you've flipped the same number consequtively. Very minor optimization concerning real world performance, but still an improvement :)